# Invalid Column name or

Tags: sql

I have the following query

```
SELECT wo.workorderid "Request ID",
       aau.first_name "Requester",
       dpt.deptname "Department",
       wotodesc.fulldescription "Description",
       sereq.udf_char3 "Owner",
       sereq.udf_char2 "Comments",
       sereq.udf_char10 "KNMgmt Priority",
       std.statusname "Request Status",
       sereq.udf_char4 "Management/Ops Communication",
       sereq.udf_char5 "Charlie Updated"
FROM workorder wo
  LEFT JOIN sduser sdu ON wo.requesterid = sdu.userid
  LEFT JOIN aaauser aau ON sdu.userid = aau.user_id
  LEFT JOIN departmentdefinition dpt ON wo.deptid = dpt.deptid
  LEFT JOIN workordertodescription wotodesc ON wo.workorderid = wotodesc.workorderid
  LEFT JOIN workorderstates wos ON wo.workorderid = wos.workorderid
  LEFT JOIN statusdefinition std ON wos.statusid = std.statusid
  INNER JOIN servicereq_3001 sereq ON wo.workorderid = sereq.workorderid
WHERE (wo.isparent = '1')
```

I need to sort by the following
the "Request Status" does not equal closed
and I need to only provide the previous month's records.

I've tried a few different options but receive a invalid column name when trying to specify a value i.e. `WHERE dbo.WorkOrderStates.STATUSID <> "3",`

other things I tried provide a "The multi-part identifier could not be bound"

I also am unsure how to sort by the last month.  I'm fairly new to SQL Coding and any assistance would help.

Comment: `"3"` is an identifier not a value. If statusid is a number you should use `statusid <> 3`

Comment: Replace dbo.workorderstates with wos because when u give an alias you must use it and replace "3" by 3

Comment: The guys have explained above what your mistakes are. Double quotes are for aliases, single quotes for strings, and numbers don't have quotes at all. And the name workorderstates cannot be used any longer once you replaced it with an alias name. Now to the task: Do you want to *sort* or *filter*? You say you want to sort, but you show a where clause. And what does "I need to only provide the previous month's records" mean? Previous to what?

Comment: What is the data type of wo.isparent? if that is a bit, then remove the single quotes around the 1.

Comment: Thanks, all of these were of great help, It's been a while working with Alias' and I should have realized I didn't need quotes.

Comment: Regarding the date range, I'm looking to further filter these to only show last month's records.  After reviewing the query, I don't believe anything currently there references the creation date of a specific entry.

Answer (score 1):

you are using alias so also in your where condition  you should use alias  again

```
  WHERE wos.STATUSID <> "3"
```

Be sure that your STATUSID is a string  otherwise you should use

```
  WHERE wos.STATUSID <>  3
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
dbo.workorderstates
```

with

```
wos
```

because when u give an alias you must use it

and replace "3" with 3

Answer (score 0):

When joining tables, tables must be aliased, try stick with the aliases, instead of referencing their original names.